# Y a-t-il une différence entre « un peu » et « peu » ?

Tags: grammaire

Y a-t-il une différence entre « un peu » et « peu » ?

Cette phrase:

> J'ai un peu de livres

Est-elle correcte?
J'ai vu dans quelque forum qu'elle est erronée.

Mais, j'ai vu que

> Donnez-moi un peu de vin

est correcte.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

L'expression **un peu de** ne s'applique qu'à des entités **indénombrables**. Livre étant dénombrable, on ne peut pas dire :

> J'ai un peu de livre

En revanche, l'expression **peu de** peut s'appliquer à des entités **dénombrables** ET **indénombrables**.

Comment: Plutôt que l'expression "des choses", qui ne recouvre pas l'emploi de *"un peu de **liberté"***, *entité https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entit%C3%A9 .* conviendrait mieux.

Comment: @cl-r : C'est noté, j'ai mis à jour. Je trouve en effet que cela fait plus propre.

Answer (score 3):

- Few / Not many = Peu (de)

> Few cats are useful = Peu de chats sont utiles

- A few = Quelques

> A few days = Quelques jours
>
> A few books = Quelques livres

- Little / Not much = Peu (de)

> The government has little support = Le gouvernement a peu de soutien

- A little = Un peu (de)

> I'd like a little coffee = J'aimerais un peu de café
>
> I'm a little sad = Je suis un peu triste
>
> You drive a little slowly = Tu conduis un peu lentement

You see it's really easy indeed, no trap here. You can even say 'trop peu (de)' for 'too few' or 'too little' ('too few cops in the streets' = 'trop peu de policiers dans les rues').

Answer (score 2):

On ne peut dire *un peu* pour des livres que l'on peut compter un par un, mais :

> J'ai quelques livres.

Au contraire, pour le vin, on sous-entendra souvent les nuances :

> J'ai *un peu* de vin.

... j'ai une petite quantité de vin,  cela peut suffire.

> J'ai *peu* de vin.

... je n'en ai pas beaucoup, pas assez ; il y a une notion de manque.

On ne pourra donc pas dire *Donnez-moi peu de vin*, car on ne demanderait pas une quantité de vin, mais *Donnez-moi un peu de vin* : donnez-moi du vin en petite quantité, ce que l'on pourrait traduire par :
*Donnez-moi 'un fond de verre', je n'ai pas envie d'être saoul*.

Comment: Encore un vote négatif injustifié, c'est dommage de ne pas respecter la nétiquette du site, cela appauvri la qualité des réponses.